# Benders with MINLP subproblem as the pricing problem of Dantzig Wolfe

Tags: reference-request, benders-decomposition, minlp, decomposition

I have a convex MINLP that after a Dantzig-Wolfe reformulation, passes most of the difficulty onto the pricing problem, which becomes a convex MINLP itself.

The pricing problem should be solvable with a Benders-like algorithm since it has a set of variables $y$ such that, when fixed, the problem is extremely easy to solve. However, these fixable variables are continuous, not discrete, and so the corresponding Benders-like subproblem has integer variables, which excludes traditional Generalized Benders.

I know that I can solve the continuous relaxation and then branch, and I have also seen Logic-based Benders Decomposition, which requires branching as well. I am afraid that this will take too much time, especially given that I am not interested in an optimal solution, I just want to generate a new column for the Dantzig-Wolfe's master.

So my question is, besides setting a high $\varepsilon$ parameter for the Benders termination criteria, are there any other $\textit{fast}$ alternatives? To summarize, the subproblem is a MINLP for which I can obtain solutions very very quickly, and I am not necessarily interested in provably optimal solutions (but still would like more than just feasibility).

As additional information, all integer variables are binary. Furthermore, for fixed $y$ variables, I can solve the subproblem directly without calling an outside solver, as everything else is fixed as well. Solving the continuous relaxation takes considerably more time, and that is why I am wary of branching approaches. Finally, the domain of $y$ is such that I do not need to worry about its feasibility.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "subproblem" you are referring to a subproblem of the pricing problem (which is itself a subproblem of the D-W problem), assuming the pricing problem is being solved by some version of Benders? Since you do not require optimality, what about "solving" either the subproblem or the entire pricing problem via heuristics?

Comment: @prubin , yes what you said is correct. Regarding solving either the pricing or the subproblem of the pricing with heuristics, that would be a viable way to do it. However, given that I have the $y$ variables, it really seems like Benders should work as well, even if it serves as just a comparison to some heuristics. Not only that, but eventually I would require optimal solutions, but that would only be relevant on the later iterations of D-W.

Comment: What about solving the subproblem by branch-and-cut with either a node limit or a time limit (or both) keeping the solution time short?

Comment: @prubin , the subproblem is very easily solvable for a fixed $y$, in the milliseconds. Are you suggesting that, for a fixed $y$, I try to solve the continuous relaxation of the subproblem by branch-and-cut while imposing limits? This is a strange case where the continuous relaxation is harder to solve than the integer counterpart.

Comment: No, I meant the integer version, not the relaxation. So your concern about the Benders decomposition is the number of Benders cycles rather than the time to solve a single subproblem? That can again be capped with an iteration (or time) limit.

Comment: @prubin Ah, I wasn't correct with my response, sorry. What I meant was that, for a branch and price, I would need to solve many costly continuous relaxations - the integer version of the problem is easier than its continuous relaxation, given a fixed $y$. I have an extremely fast way to solve the integer subproblem, but this does not give me a working dual to generate cuts to choose better values for $y$ in the next iterations, like in more common Benders.

Comment: I agree with @prubin: start by solving your MINLP pricing subproblem with a nonlinear branch-and-bound or a spatial branch-and-bound with a limited number of nodes. You can also try to solve it in a heuristic way as an MPEC. It will be quick to see if it works well enough. If it doesn't, then you can consider something more sophisticated.

Comment: @fontanf , even without fixing the $y$ variables? That I have tried, with SCIP, and it is extremely slow, it would be unusable for column generation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Do not hesitate to try with the other solvers. I would still recommend to consider a solver implementing a nonlinear branch-and-bound; or at least, solving the problem as an MPEC or solving the NLP relaxation, rounding the integer variables, and solving again the NLP relaxation with integer variables fixed. That won't require more than a few continuous relaxations. Without more information on the problem, it's difficult to see what else could be done